# Split string on first occurrence of each character

Tags: code-golf, string, text-processing

[Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42580/shorter-than-a-split-second)

Given a printable ASCII string, split it into a list of non-empty strings with a new sub-string beginning every time a character, which has not previously been seen in the same case, occurs.

#### Examples

```
"mississippi" → ["m","i","ssissi","ppi"]

"P P & C G" → ["P"," P ","& ","C ","G"]

"AAA" → ["AAA"]

"Adam" → ["A","d","a","m"]

"" → []
```

---

<sup>**Anecdote**: The result will have between 0 and 95 elements. The 95<sup>th</sup> sub-string will necessarily continue until the end because at that point, all printable ASCII characters have begun a sub-string, so every additional character will have occurred before and thus cannot cause a new sub-string to begin.</sup>

Comment: An example containing `"` and `'` seems like a good idea.

Comment: Would `""` → `[""]` be acceptable?

Comment: Can I return a newline-separated string? Since the input contains only printable ASCII, that would be unambiguous.

Comment: Yes, I thought that was a default output format for lists of strings.

Comment: @Emigna That just messes with the example output format without bringing any further clarity.

Comment: @Arnauld I [don't think so](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/14857#comment54239_14857)

Comment: @Arnauld No, `[""]` isn't *a list of non-empty substrings*.

Comment: Can the input be a list of characters, and the output be a list of lists of characters? `("A","d","d","a","m","s")` => `(("A"),("d","d"),("a"),("m"),("s"))`

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills Yes, that's covered by default I/Os.

Comment: Not sure if intentional but your `'P P & C G' → ["P"," P ","& ","C ","G"]` example uses single quotes on the left and double quotes on the right.

Comment: @cole Neither is part of the string or the output array, so I doubt it matters. They're just delimiters to show the start and end of the input, not part of it, and likewise for the elements of the output.

Comment: If outputting as a newline-separated string, can there be a leading/trailing newline?

Comment: @wastl Uh, I'll permit it in this case because it cannot indicate empty segments, although it does clash with my earlier ruling of `[""]` to be invalid. Sigh.

Comment: Can there be *both* leading and trailing newlines?

Comment: @JoKing Sure, why not?

Comment: Not specified...the first string of input Mississippi would be M i s SI ppi

Comment: @RosLuP It is actually indirectly specified in the anecdote. Since there may be up to 95 substrings, and there are only 95 printable ASCII characters, this challenge must be case sensitive. I'll add a clarification anyway.

Comment: Shouldn't `"Adam"` be `["A","da","m"]`? I'm not sure why its being split on the second `a`. (Compare to `"Mississippi"`: there is no break began the first and second `s`)

Comment: @Draco18s *which has not previously been seen in the same case*

Answer (score 24):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
QƤĠị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/w2JIjCx7u7v5/uP3opIc7Z/z/r5SbWVwMQgUFmUoA)

### Explanation

```
QƤĠị  Input is a string, say s = "adam"
 Ƥ    For each prefix of s: ["a","ad","ada","adam"]
Q     remove duplicates: ["a","ad","ad","adm"]
  Ġ   Group indices by equal values: [[1],[2,3],[4]]
   ị  Index into s: ["a","da","m"]
```

The internal representation of the strings, which the TIO link displays, is slightly different.

Comment: Can someone explain the logic of this solution?  I can see that it does work, but I can't get my head around why it works; like, I wouldn't have thought that indexing back into the original string where the deduped prefixes match would yield the answer.

Comment: The list `p` of nonempty prefixes of `s` has the same length as `s`. For each index `i`, the string `p[i]` is the prefix of `s` up to and including `s[i]`. Two adjacent chars `s[i]` and `s[i+1]` should be in the same chunk in the output if `s[i+1]` already occurred before index `i`, or in other words, in the prefix `p[i]`. This is equivalent to `p[i]` and `p[i+1]` having the same set of _unique_ characters. I compute with `QƤ` the unique characters of each prefix `p[i]`.

Comment: @Aaron Then with `Ġ` I group the _indices_ `i` of this list of strings: indices `i` and `i+1` go in the same chunk if `p[i]` and `p[i+1]` have the same unique characters. Finally, with `ị` I index back to the original string `s`, essentially grouping it into chunks in the same way as the indices `i`.

Comment: Thank you, that's starting to make a bit more sense for me.  Impressive answer!

Answer (score 10):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 9 bytes

```
q1,`.
¶$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/v9BQJ0GP69A2FbX//3Mzi4tBqKAgEwA)

#### Explanation

Match each character (`.`), discard repeated matches (`q`), discard the first match (`1,`), and insert a linefeed in front of each match `¶$&`.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
ÙSk¥sg¸«£õK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8Mzg7ENLi9MP7Ti0@tDiw1u9//9XAoIAhQAFNQVnBXcQBwA)

**Explanation**

```
Ù             # remove duplicates in input
 S            # split to a list of characters
  k           # get the (first) index of each character in the input
   ¥          # calculate delta's
    sg¸«      # append the length of the input
        £     # split the list into pieces of these sizes
         õK   # remove empty string (for the special case "" -> [])
```

Comment: For anyone coming across this answer, `¸«` can be `ª` in the new version of 05AB1E.

Answer (score 6):

## C,  <s>75</s>   <s>65</s>  63 bytes

*Thanks to @Digital Trauma for saving 10 bytes and thanks to both @gastropner and @l4m2 for saving a byte each!*

```c
f(char*s){for(int l[128]={};*s;putchar(*s++))l[*s]++||puts(l);}
```

Prints a leading newline.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NIzkjsUirWLM6Lb9IIzOvRCEn2tDIIta2utZaq9i6oLQEJK@hVaytramZE61VHKutXVMDFC7WyNG0rv0P0pGbmJmnoclVzaUABGkaSrmZxcUgVFCQqaRpDVarBGTApAMUAhTUFJwV3LFJOjo6YhVOSczFJg5i1v4HAA)

**Without a leading newline (71 bytes):**

```c
f(char*s){int l[128]={};for(l[*s]=1;*s;putchar(*s++))l[*s]++||puts(l);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NIzkjsUirWLM6M69EISfa0Mgi1ra61jotv0gjJ1qrONbW0Fqr2LqgtASkTkOrWFtbUxMsoa1dUwMULtbI0bSu/Q/SnZuYmaehyVXNpQAEaRpKuZnFxSBUUJCppGkNVqsUkwdkwhQEKAQoqCk4K7hjl3Z0dMQhkZKYi10GxKz9DwA)

Comment: [64 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NIzkjsUirWLM6Lb9IIzOvRCEn2tDIIta22qDWWqvYuqC0BKRAQ6tYW1tTMydaqzhWW7umBihcrJGjaV37H6QlNzEzT0OTq5pLAQjSNJRyM4uLQaigIFNJ0xqsVgnIgEkHKAQoqCk4K7hjk3R0dMQqnJKYi00cxKz9DwA)

Comment: `{0}` => `{}` ?

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 7 bytes

```
~:<;.1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/66xsrPUMY/9rcqUmZ@QrpCmo52YWF4NQQUGmOlwwQCFAQU3BWcEdIeTo6IjESUnMRfDU/wMA)

## Explanation

Nub sieve's chance to shine!

```
~: <;.1 ]
        ]  Input
~:         Nub sieve (1 if the character is the first instance in string)
    ;.1    Split input on 1s in nub sieve
   <       And box each
```

Comment: I was about to post exactly the same (not surprisingly) answer, it's good that I glanced your submission before that :)

Comment: @GalenIvanov I -- and I imagine most other J golfers, too -- relish the chance to use nub sieve or self-classify.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
(≢¨∪\)⊆⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG9qZv6jtgkG/9OApMajzkWHVjzqWBWj@air7VHXov//S4DC1Y96twJlioDMtEe9u6zU0xIzc9SBLKB40aPuFvX8bPVaLvXczOJiECooyFQv0Tm0Qj1XXUE9E4ghwkAGSIZLPUAhQEFNwVnBHaIqACgBFAGSaiDCGUS4A5U5OjoCFTzqagKzgPyUxFyIDjCLS129RMHgUe8WkAp1AA)

Comment: But, but… Oh my.

Comment: I suspected you might have posted this challenge because of the new primitive (⊆). Evidently not :)

Comment: It looks like an embarrassed Kirby holding a baby bottle.

Comment: Can be just three characters now `≠⊂⊢`

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
Ùvyy¶ì.;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8MyyyspD2w6v0bP@/z83s7gYhAoKMgE)

---

Always will output 1 preceding newline, which is constant and not indicative of a split, the 10-byte alternative that does not output a preceding newline is `Ùvyy¶ì.;}¦`, you [can try that here](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8MyyyspD2w6v0bOuPbTs///czOJiECooyAQA). According to Adam a preceding or trailing newline is acceptable.

---

```
Input      = mississippi                               | Stack
-----------#-------------------------------------------+----------------------------------
Ù          # Push unique letters of first input.       | ['misp']
 v         # Iterate through each unique letter.       | []
  yy       # Push 2 copies of the letter (or yD)       | ['m','m']
    ¶      # Push a newline char.                      | ['m','m','\n']
     ì     # Prepended to the letter.                  | ['m','\nm']
      .;   # Replace first instance with '\n + letter' | ['\nmississippi']
```

**After each iteration we get:**

```
['\nmississippi'] > ['\nm\nississippi'] > ['\nm\ni\nssissippi'] > ['\nm\ni\nssissi\nppi']
```

**Which is:**

```
m
i
ssissi
ppi
```

Comment: Nice! Beat me by a fair margin ;)

Comment: @Emigna this was sitting as a comment on your answer for 2 days then I just posted it b/c no response haha :P.

Comment: Weird, haven't seen any notification on that. Different enough for its own answer though :)

Comment: @Emigna well, I mean, I deleted it haha.

Comment: Skipping the loop saves a byte `ÙSD¶ì.;`. Not sure why we didn't think of that before :P

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>58 52</s>  40 bytes

```perl6
{$/={};.comb.classify({$+=!$/{$_}++}).sort».value».join}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcqlBmppdszcWVW6mglpyfkqpg@79aRd@2utZaLzk/N0kvOSexuDgzrVKjWkXbVlFFv1olvlZbu1ZTrzi/qOTQbr2yxJzSVCCdlZ@ZV/u/OLFSAWSKhlJuJlAbEBUUZCpp6hUArbPmgsuqBygEKKgpOCu4q2PIKTk6OiphEU1JzMUiDBP6DwA)

```perl6
*.comb.classify({$+=!(%){$_}++}).sort».value».join
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcqlBmppdszcWVW6mglpyfkqpg@19LLzk/N0kvOSexuDgzrVKjWkXbVlFDVbNaJb5WW7tWU684v6jk0G69ssSc0lQgnZWfmfffmqs4sVIBZIKGUm4mUCMQFRRkKmnqFQCtQpJVD1AIUFBTcFZwV8eQU3J0dFTCIpqSmItFGCb0HwA)

```perl6
*.classify({$+=!(%){$_}++}).sort».value
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##TY5BasMwEEX3OsWv6jp2XbTMxmRhsug20AMExZapEssSGilgXJ8su17MFYG2gVnMe/BnvlN@2K6RFK5b0daMmQl5j936KtpBEul@Kuas2j0VL@WcHZeqWkpB1ofvm7jKIaq1Zs9fMPKioAOUJK08gkU6@QY5dvd97JSncKdPBRuDi4FRPKHT5AY5ocBH8MgIJWYGUFIZidaak8j79Ops9Shc6soWxn5D3OhUMI1zmtd/enPAATn2eN/8S940DX/ETppH5vX6Aw)
(input is a list of characters, and output is a list of lists of characters)

### Expanded:

```perl6
*                   # parameter for WhateverCode lambda

  .classify(        # classify that list
    {
        $           # anonymous scalar state variable (accumulator)

      +=            # increment it if:

        !           # Bool invert the following
          (
            %       # anonymous hash state variable
          ){ $_ }++ # look to see if the character was seen already
    }
  ).sort\           # sort the Pairs by key (makes the order correct)
  ».value           # get the value from each Pair
```

---

The output from `classify` is

```perl6
{ # Hash
  1 => ['m'],
  2 => ['i'],
  3 => ['s','s','i','s','s','i'],
  4 => ['p','p','i'],
}
```

And `.sort` just turns it into:

```perl6
[
  1 => ['m'],
  2 => ['i'],
  3 => ['s','s','i','s','s','i'],
  4 => ['p','p','i'],
]
```

`».value` removes the keys

```perl6
[
  ['m'],
  ['i'],
  ['s','s','i','s','s','i'],
  ['p','p','i'],
]
```

Comment: Why would the keys ever be out of order? Is insertion order not tracked like a `HashMap` vs. a `LinkedHashMap` in Java where the order is based on memory vs. insert order?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn No version of Perl has had ordered Hashes. In fact Perl 5 version 18 made Hashes more randomized which helps make a certain type of denial of service attack less possible, and has also caused buggy user code to expose it's buggy behaviour more often. Now someone could (and likely has) implement a class which does keep track, but that would take more than 5 characters to load and use.

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 39 bytes

```hs
foldl(\s c->s++['\n'|all(/=c)s]++[c])""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZclBCsIwEEDRvacYhkJbSvEEEXIO00WYGA1O0sHp0rM72m2Fv3r/EfV5Y7bsguWVEw9BgeaLTtO1D61/R@bh7GjU5Se0jIhWY2ngIK0nAJBXaRt0kAFrUd0TKXhYPsX6Z94fCe1DmeNdbSaRLw)

Inserts a newline symbol before every character that appears for the first time, resulting in a newline-separated string, with a leading newline. Prepend `lines.` to produce a list.

---

**[Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 55 bytes**

```hs
(""%)
_%[]=[]
p%s|(a,b)<-span(`elem`s!!0:p)s=a:(a++p)%b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZclBDsIgEEDRPaeYEkkgtYnrRhacozZ22oISgU4cl55djNua/NX7d@SHT6kGe6laSmXEVQ2jHUZBit8aj7M5d0xY9OSTzxM3zaknwxZ7jW1LRs01YyxgYd0EANAzlhccIIDMkfkXUZS75VbMf@bcnmT9LCHhjWu3EH0B)

Repeatedly takes the prefix the first character plus the non-unique characters that follow it.

Comment: @WheatWizard Oops, yes, `lines`.

Comment: Might want to do `tail.lines` to remove the extra empty string now that I think about it.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes

Thanks, Erik the Outgolfer for saving 1 byte!

```apl
⊢⊂⍨⍳∘≢∊⍳⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qLdP/VHfVOdIdfXixJwSdfVH3S1AfrCrXqizrwuQ2zYhKb9CIT9PQbfYNjczBSjStTg1LzEpJzXY0ScEpLp3jbrC/zSgwkddix51NT3qXfGod/OjjhmPOhc96ugCsXtX/P@fpqCem1lcDEIFBZnqXEB@gEKAgpqCs4I7mOfo6AihUxJzwQx1AA)

## Explanation:

`⍳⍨`: For each character, get the index of its first occurrence. e.g `mississippi -> 1 2 3 3 2 3 3 2 9 9 2`

`⍳∘≢`: The range from 1 to the length of the input.

`∊`: Membership. e.g `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11∊1 2 3 3 2 3 3 2 9 9 2 -> 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0`

`⊢⊂⍨`: Partition the input string with new partitions starting at `1`s in the vector above

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qLdP/VHfVOdIdfXixJwSdfVH3S1AfrCrXqizrwuQ2zYhKb9CIT9PQbfYNjczBSjStTg1LzEpJzXY0ScEpLp3jbrC/zSgwkddix51NT3qXfGod/OjjhmPOhc96ugCsXtX/P@fpqCem1lcDEIFBZnqXEB@gEKAgpqCs4I7mOfo6AihUxJzwQx1AA) (monadic `fg` and monadic `f∘g` behave the same)

Comment: Why `∊` instead of `=`?

Comment: At the time of writing, I hadn't considered that the indices would be in the correct positions. Although it is clear that they are

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 bytes

```
¬â r@=iRUbY
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=rOIgckA9aVJVYlk=&input=J21pc3Npc3NpcHBpJw==)

#### Explanation

This was inspired by [Magic Octopus Urn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59376/magic-octopus-urn)'s [05AB1E solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156291/42545).

```
¬â r@=iRUbY    Implicit: U = input string
¬â             Split U into chars, and keep only the first occurrence of each.
   r@          Reduce; for each char Y in this string...
        UbY      Find the first index of Y in U.
      iR         Insert a newline at this index in U.
     =           Set U to the result.
               As reduce returns the result of the last function call, this gives the
               value of U after the final replacement, which is implicitly printed.
```

Comment: Japt is having an identity crisis here, it's calling itself Ruby for some reason. `iRUbY`!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>81</s> 74 bytes

```python
def f(s):d=sorted(map(s.find,set(s)));print map(lambda a,b:s[a:b],d,d[1:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY29CsMwEIP3PsXhobHBFNrRIUPI0DV7CMThbGqof8jd0qd3Y1oQkuBDqHz4ldOjVnQevCRlcKB8sEMZbZF08yGhJscnUqovR0gMjbxt3NGC1buhxZp91ahxuZtVVXbEwyJiIGoqJQgtZpjhChM8zz6OY3O08QyxXnw@gCEkaEvz@9h4673k/2XX1S8)

Comment: Save two with [list(set(map(s.find,s)))](https://tio.run/##LY0xC8MgFIT3/oqHQ6NUCu1oyCAdupXsIsSgUqExkveW9s/bWArH3S33XXnTc83XWn2IEDkK5YdXQuIYiC@ucDzHlL1EIURftpTJoHFqtnHdwMkZUoZPKtxLby7KnsxjzcEKWykgDYYtCbGplMQkG2GEI9zgvnetdXPvlj2YPTQgNVxbqt8VTDT1kdP/uevqFw)

Comment: @JonathanAllan it's a misleading side-effect, `set` do not keep order, counter-proof -> `s='c'*6+'a'*100+'b'`

Comment: I know we cannot rely on it in future implementations but *I believe* given ordered integers we maintain order in the set due to the hash of an integer being the integer (as you have shown the same is not true for other objects -- can you find a word that does not work with my alternative?).

Comment: @JonathanAllan [not true either](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EoTi1RCPaUMdIx0zH0MAgVvP/fwA)

Comment: Ah, fair enough, my belief was false!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 37 bytes

*Saved 7 bytes: a leading newline was explicitly allowed (Thanks @Shaggy!)*

Takes input as an array of characters. Outputs a newline-separated string.

```js
s=>s.map(c=>s[c]=s[c]?c:`
`+c).join``
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>s.map(c=>s[c]=s[c]?c:`
`+c).join``

;[
  [..."mississippi"],
  [..."P P & C G"],
  [..."AAA"],
  [..."Adam"],
  [...""]    
]
.forEach(s => console.log('{' + f(s) + '}\n'))
```

Comment: [Leading newlines are allowed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156170/split-on-first-unique#comment380534_156170) so you can get this down to [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYzLCsIwFAX3fkUWIgnq/QAhldCF2@7TwA1pKynNAyNSKP32mIhwmDOrmfVHJ/Oy8X31YRjzxHPiTQKnIzVFpFG84m5ueMCzYTAH6xGzCT6FZYQlPKlEZ1Oqi9HiBTvSkRNpyaO4EKJy0K4cql945Q1ux22iEgBWxfYd/93e9x5Z/gI)

Answer (score 3):

### brainfuck, 66 bytes

```
,[>+[<[>+<<-<+>>-]>[>]<<[[+]++++++++++.>>>]<]<[>+<-]>>>[>>]<<-.>,]
```

Formatted:

```
,
[
  >+
  [
    <[>+< <-<+>>-]
    >[>]
    <<[[+]++++++++++.>>>]
    <
  ]
  <[>+<-]
  >>>[>>]
  <<-.>,
]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##PcpRCoAwDAPQA3XbCUIuUvqhglBEGQ7PXzs/DCEf4a334tf@bEdEUYoiB6gQshqVBqiKyZ9G5mmfS8E0E9XGYhGnjzHbu78)

The leading newline in the output (which is only printed if the input is non-empty) can be removed at the cost of 5 bytes by replacing the body `x` of the main (outermost) loop with `.>,[x]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ŒQœṗ⁸Ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opMCjkx/unP6occfDHV3/D7cfnfRw54z//5VyM4uLQaigIFMJAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>94</s> 87 bytes

```r
function(s,n=nchar(s),g=substring)g(s,d<-which(!duplicated(g(s,1:n,1:n))),c(d[-1]-1,n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYkxDsMgDAC/kmSyJRhYq@QlVYbEFLCUOgiD@nwapLvhdKWHabU9NKHKt4Aa2YTSUUDRxE3bqbWwRIzP8qv9JaYEs2/5Yjrqx8MY7iVDRDQE/m3dbp15sgdYvqw6yJkX7H8)

Returns a (possibly empty) list of substrings.

*Thanks to Michael M for saving 7 bytes!*

Comment: `function(s,n=nchar(s),g=substring)g(s,d<-which(!duplicated(g(s,1:n,1:n))),c(d[-1]-1,n))` would be shorter - and of course a bit uglier...

Comment: Why `substring` instead of `substr`?

Comment: @MichaelM Very nice! I still have to add the `if(n)` in there because `substring` throws an error for empty string input.

Comment: @plannapus `substr` returns a vector of length equal to its first input while `substring` returns one of length equal to the longest of its inputs.

Comment: @Giuseppe: Dropping the "if(n)" in R 3.4.3 maps the empty input string "" to the empty output string "", which should be fine(?)

Comment: @MichaelM oh I see. The `strsplit` approach needed it and I must have tested a version of that instead of yours. My bad.

Comment: It is pure luck that `substring("", 1:0, 1:0)` does not complaint :)

Answer (score 2):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download/), 19 bytes

**Solution:**

```
$[#x;(*:'.=x)_;,]x:
```

**Examples:**

```
q)k)$[#x;(*:'.=x)_;,]x:"mississippi"
,"m"
,"i"
"ssissi"
"ppi"
q)k)$[#x;(*:'.=x)_;,]x:"P P & C G"
,"P"
" P "
"& "
"C "
,"G"
q)k)$[#x;(*:'.=x)_;,]x:"AAA"
"AAA"
q)k)$[#x;(*:'.=x)_;,]x:"Adam"
,"A"
,"d"
,"a"
,"m"
q)k)$[#x;(*:'.=x)_;,]x:""
,[""]
```

**Explanation:**

8 bytes is just to handle `""`...

```
$[#x;(*:'.=x)_;,]x: / the solution
                 x: / save input as variable x
$[  ;         ; ]   / $[condition;true;false]
  #x                / length of x ("" has length 0, i.e. false)
             _      / cut right at left indices
     (      )       / do together
          =x        / group x into key/value (char!indices)
         .          / return value (get indices)
      *:'           / first (*:) each
               ,    / enlist, "" => [""]
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>61</s> <s>54</s> 52 bytes

Takes input as an array of characters.

```js
s=>s.map(x=>a[x]?a[y]+=x:a[x]=a[++y]=x,a=[],y=-1)&&a
```

---

### Try it

```js
o.innerText=JSON.stringify((f=
s=>s.map(x=>a[x]?a[y]+=x:a[x]=a[++y]=x,a=[],y=-1)&&a
)([...i.value=""]));oninput=_=>o.innerText=JSON.stringify(f([...i.value]))
```

```html
<input id=i><pre id=o></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>22 17</s> 14 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Emigna*

```
i:::a$1g?!o1po
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9PKyipRxTDdXjHfsCD////czOJiECooyAQA)

Prints a leading and trailing newline.

It keeps track of which letters have already appeared by `p`utting a copy of the character at that corresponding spot on the second row, and printing a newline if the value fetched from that position was not 1. Ends in an error when it tries to print `-1`

Comment: Great use of `g/p`! [16 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9PKyipRxTDdvi7fsCDHPv///9zM4mIQKijIBAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 30 bytes

Includes `+1` for `p`

Give input without trailing newline on STDIN. Output is also without trailing newline:

```
echo -n adam | perl -pE 's%.%$v{$&}+++!pos?$&:$/.$&%eg'; echo
```

If you don't care about leading and trailing newlines this `25` (`+3` for `-p` because the code contains `'`) also works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s%%$/x!$v{$'&~v0}++%eg
```

Comment: Great solution as always! Based on the test cases provided, you don't need to name your hash, you can do `${$&}++`. It's not as robust, but might suffice for this challenge? Also, there's been a consensus on meta that `perl -p` doesn't need an additional byte, you just need to have the header as ``Perl with `-p` `` instead of just Perl. I'm trying to remember to do that myself...

Comment: @DomHastings The annecdote about at most 95 possible strings quite strongly implies that `1` is valid, in which case the `v` is needed. Regarding the counting, I mostly follow https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7539/51507 which to me is the most consistent meta post about counting perl.

Comment: Always nice to learn from the master. Specifically, in this case, `&~v0` for grabbing the first character. Thank you for joining this site and sharing your long expertise.

Comment: You can use Strawberry Perl, which uses `"` instead of `'` with `-e`, and then you can count the `-ep` as +1 rather than +3. (Tested.)

Comment: Redoing your 30 byte solution which does not put in a leading newline, I think you can save by using a negative lookbehind to skip the first newline.  That way, the use of `pos` can be eliminated, also removing the need for the conditional operator.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YVcNeMU5TT1VFv0JRpaRaRa1WW1tPRU01Nf3/f49MhZKM1PiiVIWs7H/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6xYAAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ç↓‼►▐NVh
```

[Run and debug online](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%C3%A7%E2%86%93%E2%80%BC%E2%96%BA%E2%96%90NVh&i=mississippi%0A%0AP+P+%26+C+G%0A%0AAAA%0A%0AAdam%0A&a=1&m=1)

The ascii representation of the same program is this.

```
c{[Ii=}(m
```

For each character, it splits when the index of the current character is the current position.

```
c            copy the input
 {    }(     split the string when the result of the enclosed block is truthy
  [          duplicate the input string under the top of the stack
   I         get the character index of the current character
    i=       is it equal to the iteration index?
        m    print each substring
```

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>11</s> 6 bytes

```
⌈`∘⊐⊸⊔
```

[Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oyIYOKImOKKkOKKuOKKlAoKRiAiTWlzc2lzc2lwcGki)

#### Explanation

```
⌈`∘⊐⊸⊔
   ⊐    Classify: replace each letter with a number based on the order of
        their first occurrences
⌈`∘     Scan with maximum: replace each number with the largest number so far
    ⊸⊔  Group the original string into those buckets
```

A couple of worked examples:

```
"dodos"            "Mississippi"
⟨ 0 1 0 1 2 ⟩       ⟨ 0 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 3 3 1 ⟩
⟨ 0 1 1 1 2 ⟩       ⟨ 0 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 ⟩
⟨ "d" "odo" "s" ⟩   ⟨ "M" "i" "ssissi" "ppi" ⟩
```

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>115</s> <s>91</s> 77 bytes

```
	N =INPUT
S	N LEN(1) . Y	:F(END)
	S =S Y
	N SPAN(S) . OUTPUT REM . N	:(S)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NPwdbTLyA0hCsYyPRx9dMw1FTQU4jktHLTcPVz0eTiDFawDVaI5ALKBgc4@mkEg6T9Q0OAWhSCXH2BHD9OK6AoF1D1//@5mcXFIFRQkAkA)

Prints the substrings separated by newlines.

Explanation:

line `S` (for `SPLIT`) doesn't actually split, but instead extracts the first character of `N` and saves it (`.`) to `Y`. On `F`ailure, it jumps to `END`. The match should only fail when `N` is the empty string. Thus, when the input is empty, it jumps directly to `END` and outputs nothing.

`S = S Y` concatenates `Y` onto `S`.

`SPAN(S)` greedily matches a run of characters in `S`, and sends it (`.`) to `OUTPUT`, setting (`.`) `N` to the `REM`aining characters of `N` (if there are any). Then it jumps back to `S`.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 62 bytes

```
r#c|any(elem c)r=init r++[last r++[c]]|1<2=r++[[c]]
foldl(#)[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYk7DsIwEAX7nGLlUCSKUkCNC58juFj5AyvWjmWnQcrZMbLSBekV82ZeWN6OuXr5qH5ly0M/LrrLvdkxfgbHLoAZs6RIG@RpWhjLAUbr/Xq/ycbt1IAUQYJdOwBImeIGF/AgApXSlhKJU1IWw59T6qxE/RrP@Cx1Nin9AA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 68 bytes

```
s=>s.map(c=>o[c]?t+=c:(t&&m.push(t),t=o[c]=c),t='',o=m=[])&&[...m,t]
```

Takes input as a list of characters.

**Test cases:**

```js
let f=
s=>s.map(c=>o[c]?t+=c:(t&&m.push(t),t=o[c]=c),t='',o=m=[])&&[...m,t]

console.log(f([...'mississippi']));
console.log(f([...'P P & C G']));
console.log(f([...'AAA']));
console.log(f([...'Adam']));
console.log(f([...'']));
```

Comment: I had a similar solution and asked if `[""]` was acceptable for the last test case. [But it's not](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156170/split-on-first-unique#comment380487_156170). :-(

Comment: Oh, well, you got a much better solution anyway : )

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>65</s> <s>62</s> 58 bytes

```ruby
->s,*a{s.size.times{|i|(i==s.index(c=s[i])?a:a[-1])<<c}
a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/NasMwEITveopFh8QujmivIWowOeTquxFla8lUELvCK0N@nGd3V0nrgnY1mvlWSMP4eZlbPW/eqXjBW/aqlCJF/upy1WG4TX7KvNakfG/dOWs01d7ke9xivXkz@W7X3AXe5@gofjRIjkBDLQBq2XmitELwskhnWUhW8umySIExRYLXFVSwggMc1wmtOGWD@yq1Q2rHP1aWZfm4MO2LZ7F7moxaLuTqljhFxggjxP9DlcPmC@w3TL4PYyzAnYNrorMTjwyOxlPkv7T1IzXshcH3cUn0wsMeZBaQKAcJW9Yt@hPrNPKLC9fbef4B)

A lambda accepting a string and returning an array of strings.

Approach: For each index, either append the character at that index in `s` to the result array, or to the last string in the result array. `String#index` returns the index of the first instance of the argument.

-2 bytes: Initialize `a` as a splat argument instead of on its own line. *Thanks, [Value Ink](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194/value-ink)!*

-1 byte: Use `c=s[i]`...`c` instead of `s[i]`...`s[i]`. *Thanks, [Value Ink](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194/value-ink)!*

-4 bytes: Use `.times` instead of `.map`

Comment: [-3 bytes by using some assignment tricks.](https://tio.run/##RY/NasMwEITveopFh8QujmivIWowOeTquxFla8lUELvCK0N@nGd3V0nrgnY1mvlWSMP4eZlbPW/eqXjBW/aqlCJF/upy1WG4TX7KvNakfG/dOWs01d7ke9xivXkz@W7X3AXe5@gofjRIjkBDLQBq2XmitELwskhnWUhW8umySIExRYLXFVSwggMc1wmtOGWD@yq1Q2rHP1aWZfm4MO2LZ7F7moxaLuTqljhFxggjxP9DlcPmC@w3TL4PYyzAnYNrorMTjwyOxlPkv7T1IzXshcH3cUn0wsMeZBaQKAcJW9Yt@hPrNPKLC9fbef4B "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

```python
lambda s:reduce(lambda r,c:r+'\n'[c in r:]+c,s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU09D8IgFJzlV7ww2DZlciTpQBxcu7cdkI9IIpS8h4O/HotxMbncx3B3@V0ee7pUP631qePdaiCJzr6M638ZhZE4dmvqFgMhAcptNIKGWhwVggkWHgNRQ86BCz7DDGe4wu3wSqnGVsdD@MaY3xGozXzbkp0yhlTA9zQIaCf1b@0D)

Outputs a newline-separated string. Barely beats the program version:

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 48 bytes**

```python
r=''
for c in input():r+='\n'[c in r:]+c
print r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8hWXZ0rLb9IIVkhMw@ICkpLNDStirRt1WPy1KPBgkVWsdrJXAVFmXklCkX//yvlZhYXg1BBQaYSAA)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 317 bytes

```
function SplitOnFirstUnique($s){
    $len = strlen($s); 
    $output = [];
    $newstring = '';
    for ($i=0; $i < $len ; $i++) { 
        $newstring = $newstring.$s[$i];
        if(!in_array($s[$i] , $output  )){
            $output[] = $newstring;
            $newstring = '';
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7LCsIwELz3K9YSMEER71G8efUgnoqISKsLul03CSLit9eE@EB0CGEzMzsZPnA3mfGBCxYkvxG95CP6Bc1RnF8RnkOtyxM6lw4zlsbYrgm089gS/DErZ24FRKhjTTAF5yUOibaQ@TZ4Dj5K1dpmhupLtCHtI9nvZ7JpBbTC6diCQpjkuDQPBgZuOepn@fMYKVcpfH6QgI3uIW22IturziIM32XAPFu/Y7NQrb9S7bfnX@@Ee/G5pfZB6JVni3vXPQA)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! I've edited your post to our standard format, and added a link to Try It Online so other people can test your code. The aim of Code Golf is to write the shortest code possible, and I can see a couple of ways to make this shorter, like using shorter variable names and leaving out some of the whitespace. You can check out the [general tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) and [PHP tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/tips-for-golfing-in-php) pages for some more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 79 bytes

```
func[s][foreach c next unique/case append s"^@"[print copy/part s s: find s c]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcqxCsIwFIXhPU9x6OAm3TtZHFyLa4gQkhvM0PSa20Kl5NmjRXDr4Wz/l8nXO3loo0JXw5KcFqPDlMm6JxwSrTOWFF8Ltc4KwTJT8pDmcWk055hmuInfLds8QyAdQtw7nDE1YBujyH7mWNTPb@f/ivqSAQNOuOJ2BPq@P0zejketqPoB)

### Ungolfed:

```
f: func [s] [
    b: next unique/case append s "^@"  ; append `null` to the end of the string, than
                                       ; find the unique characters and 
                                       ; store all except the first to b  
    foreach c b [                      ; for each character in b
        print copy/part s s: find s c  ; print the part of the string to
                                       ; where the character is found and
                                       ; set the beginning of the string to that position
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>193</s> <s>169</s> <s>155</s> 151 bytes

```java
s->{for(int l=s.length(),i=0,j;i<l;i++)if(s.indexOf(s.charAt(i))==i){for(j=i;++j<l&&s.indexOf(s.charAt(j))!=j;);System.out.println(s.substring(i,j));}}
```

-14 bytes thanks to *@raznagul* (for something obvious I somehow missed myself..)
-3 bytes thanks to *@O.O.Balance* (again for something obvious I somehow missed myself.. :S)

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZE/b4MwEMX3foorA7IFQd0dV0IdOjWNlLHqYAwk5xqDOBO1ivjs1BDGDEh3kv/87vk92air2rVd5Uz5M2mriOBDobs9AaDzVV8rXcFh3gJcWyxBs5Pv0Z2BuAinY@hQ5JVHDQdwIGGi3eutbnsWFMBKymzlzv7CeIryJTUC91ZgknCsGWXoyur3c17pi@pzz5BzKZEvAkaiSBKzt3H8gDScP0sjuDj9ka@arB181gVv3roA0VDQ4pRhGkgxjpO4m@2Gwgazq@clVRMyr8G@vhW/53WZZlGDRHN1HUZLYoAHz603y8QRjhDDG7xv5PM830qWqtmIbsTUdsXCKlg7Wr9@nP4B)

```java
s->{                    // Method with String parameter and no return-type
  for(int l=s.length(), //  The length of the input-String
          i=0,j;        //  Index integers
      i<l;i++)          //  Loop `i` from 0 to `l` (exclusive)
    if(s.indexOf(s.charAt(i))==i){
                        //   If the character at index `i` hasn't occurred yet:
      for(j=i;++j<l     //    Inner loop `j` from `i` to `l` (exclusive),
          &&s.indexOf(s.charAt(j))!=j;);
                        //     as long as the character at index `j` has already occurred
      System.out.println(//    Print:
        s.substring(i,j));}}
                        //     The substring of the input from index `i` to `j` (exclusive)
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `if(l<1)`. If `l` is `0` the loop shouldn't be executed anyway as `0<0` is `false`.

Comment: @raznagul Not sure how I missed that, but you're complete right!.. >.>

Comment: You're setting `i=0` twice. You can save 3 bytes by dropping the second one: `for(;i<l;i++)`

Comment: @O.O.Balance Not sure how that happened.. :S But thanks for noticing! :)

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 73 bytes

```
{$r=@();$h=@{};[char[]]$ARGS[0]|%{if(!($h[$_]++)){$r+=""};$r[-1]+=$_};$r}
```

### Usage

```
PS> & {$r=@();$h=@{};[char[]]$ARGS[0]|%{if(!($h[$_]++)){$r+=""};$r[-1]+=$_};$r} "mississipi" | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
["m","i","ssissi","pi"]
```

Comment: you can save some bytes - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZFPb4JAEMXvfIrpZBUQaNJrGxKJB66kPTaNQVkiEVzKYmyDfHb6Rq0Sfo@ZN38gbGtOurM7XdeTKimmYVK7eDmMbyp5Tz/OM@oXv@fZUJXek9o9q3UQ@IPqgjhkRk/3Gb18BbFaj47qptFxlp5DuEKPm8paudu24pC44ZAR8NVEIL5/a3YzymhOK0pdtGaoIofORVYi6b2XkySRhfJ4eEXeXEy0FiAHzaPMdH9TVFd7TYXRlg6mp5Pp9rTR2/xoNZmSFm7oRqAGFdgDDQgUwEhiJTsYSC/RSSKsgW6kvAU5wEqZAKXUFq7v@HSmGQ2Xj1E2JKV/Wr3tdYE/r9ZXu9P2WPcw5jgQZS8mK49vBY70N9/n2H/9n2BnnP4A "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 40 bytes

```ruby
->a{i=0
a.slice_when{a.index(_2)==i+=1}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3NXTtEqszbQ24EvWKczKTU-PLM1LzqhP1MvNSUis04o00bW0ztW0Na2uh6pULFNyiVcujcxUyFYqBEEYWAGFmbKxeSX58IkTpggUQGgA)

Comment: This isn't reusable - `$.` isn't reset on every iteration, and it might not be set to 0 if the user uses `gets` or `$<`.

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan That’s correct.

Comment: What I mean is that this is currently invalid: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4940/92689

Comment: On the other hand though, it's perfectly valid to remove the outer `[*` and `]`.

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan That’s unfortunate. Thanks for the pointer. As for the `[*…]`, without it you get an Enumerator instead of an array. Is that valid?

Comment: Yes. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753/92689 Ruby's enumerator is basically Python's version of a generator, so it applies.

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan Thanks. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-pl`, 22 bytes

```perl
s@.@$/x!$h{$&}++.$&@ge
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoic0AuQCQveCEkaHskJn0rKy4kJkBnZSIsImFyZ3MiOiItcGwiLCJpbnB1dCI6Ik1pc3Npc3NpcHBpXG5QIFAgJiBDIEdcbkFBQVxuQWRhbVxuIn0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog APL)](https://www.dyalog.com/products.htm), 3 bytes

```
≠⊂⊢
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qpTIxJz89PrEgZ8GCpaUlaboWKx91LnjU1fSoaxGEf3NR2qO2CY_6pnoF-_tpPOrte9TV_Kh3zaPeLQhG31Q_d9cQDbiAEUgkUFndPbXEOT83NzEvxSczL9WxKL1YXdNQkwsoCzQyTUE9N7O4GIQKCjLVEaIBCgEKagrOCu5IYo6Ojsi8lMRcJK46xKUwHwAA)

`≠` the Boolean mask indicating first occurrence of each character…

`⊂` splits…

`⊢` the argument

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>22</s> <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
1>`(.)(?<!\1.+)
¶$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/f0C5BQ09Tw95GMcZQT1uT69A2FbX//3Mzi4tBqKAgEwA) Edit: Saved <s>2</s> 3 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder.

Comment: @MartinEnder Ah yes, the lookahead was an artefact from a previous iteration that had to deal with overlapping matches, but I don't think I can use the non-word boundary because I need to be able to support all printable ASCII characters.

Comment: Oh, right, you can still use a limit though: https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/f0C5BQ09Tw95GMcZQT1uT69A2FbX//3Mzi4tBqKAgEwA

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 200 bytes

My first (I think?) attempt at code golf:

```js
function split(s) {let x=[];let y=[];let z="";let w=1;for(l of s.split('')){if (x.includes(l)){z+=l;}else{w=!w;if (w) {y.push(z);z='';w=0;}z+=l;x.push(l);}}y.push(z);if (y.join('')==0) y=[];return y;}
```

Comment: You can remove almost all the spaces, no?

Comment: @Adám Ah, yes. Thanks for that tip. It's now 200 bytes.

Comment: Ideas: one-letter function name, remove most remaining spaces, remove trailing semicolons: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7LDsIgEEV/BbspEyOpa8KXGBdNC0ozAulQ6SN8e6W6MJnM4uTcmTu075a60YZ4cb7X@24m10XrHTOcYJvV7S6XY62qqiTqyJK6SuNHjswbRoIC2sjrGmCzhs/Cug6nXhPHQtazwqyR9JbUKckiJNgWESZ68hXKzbqWSTX58OT84wg5/5USWcTgrTteKNXAt8yo4zQ6tuS98448aoH@wQ2vXpbomBBsBbB/AA "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: In general, [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript) may help you.

Comment: I would remove the `let`s and replace `function split(s)` with `s=>`. Note: you don't need to name the function unless it's recursive.

Comment: You can replace `s.split('')` with `[...s]`, but I would map through the array instead of looping through it. `for(l of [...s])` -> [...s].map(l=>`

Comment: I would also replace the if-else with a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). I know this is your first golfing attempt. I would recommend visiting [Tips for golfing in JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript) :)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 84 bytes

```
a@{}={};a@b_:=a@b[[;;(c@b=Position[b,Tally[b][[-1,1]]][[1,1]])-1]]~Append~b[[c@b;;]]
```

Defines a function `a`. Takes a list of characters as input and returns a list of lists of characters as output. Uses a basic recursive structure.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, 37 bytes

```perl
for$a(32..126){$a=chr$a;s/\Q$a/\n$a/}
```

Run through printable ASCII and insert a newline before the first appearance

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8tv0glUcPYSE/P0MhMs1ol0TY5AyhiXawfE6iSqB@TByRq///PzSwuBqGCgkyuAIUABTUFZwV3LkdHRy7HlMTcf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA)

Comment: For `30` (use a literal newline): `eval";y/ -~/~ -}/;s/a/\na/"x95`

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 74 bytes

```lua
t={}print(((...):gsub(".",load"c=...a=(t[c]or'\\n')..c t[c]=''return a")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchNCoAgEEDhq4ibmYGYAwSeJFuYRQim4s8qOvtU8Dbfi8OJdHM/pYbUEZGZaT7b2FCznmJ2u/bmm85gX/yaK1ibgJi9@m0A6tFHTcppIhKRK7T2V0p4AQ)

Prints one additional leading newline.

Answer (score 0):

## GNU sed, 37 bytes

(includes +1 for `-r` option)

```sed
s/./\n&/g
:a
s/((.).*)\n\2/\1\2/
ta
```

We start by prepending a newline to every character in the string; then in the loop, we remove those that precede a second or subsequent occurrence.

Note that newline can't occur in the input, as that's the separator between strings.  And it's not classified as a *printable* character.

Answer (score 0):

### C++, 176 bytes

```cpp
#include<string>
#include<set>
std::string*s(std::string e){auto*r=new std::string[96];std::set<int>u;for(char p:e){if(u.find(p)==u.end())u.insert(p);r[u.size()]+=p;}return r;}
```

Returns an array of strings, valid strings member of the answer array are not of size 0. 
Each call of the function allocate `sizeof(std::string)*96`, with the pointer returned, and must be `delete[]`d after usage.
Code to test :

```cpp
auto tests = {
    "mississippi","P P & C G", "AAA", "Adam",""
};

for (const auto& a : tests) {

    std::string* res = s(a);

    for (int i = 0; i < 96; ++i) {
        if (res[i].size() > 0)
            std::cout << '\"' << res[i] << "\", ";
    }

    delete[] res;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Would it save bytes to use `#define` or `using` for `std::string`?

Comment: `using S=std::string` should save ~10 bytes.

Comment: Oh, in addition, `auto` can be changed to `S` as well.

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 63 bytes

```
func u(v){for(;j++<split(v,A,"");)S[s]=S[s+=m[A[j]]++?0:1]A[j]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/BTsMwEETv/opRWkgiFym94loo6oFrpR6jHNzGgQ2OE2K7gKp@e0igNyS6Wq1m5jJv1cfbONbBHhGSU3quuyERDecb1xvyyWmVr6IoFem@cKWcDpdtkRdNWXL@lD2uy1lfxnNIllkqcGMWW2UMYtfrIykT46cDc7mnzrK5m@Ra0EY6QZyn6Aeyvo7iOxcjWmFfUCmw2M0ptDq@wvlJv8CFYeiCrXSFwxfcFBmN99B57ViljfYae9FIJzNxte3lD5vRasBJDaQORjtMNLD608OQ1ehq@MmwZSYjbB4QLbN/P/1lJNsHf4UcW3Ju3r4ntsMO99jiOWZ5nrO8Ui1j3w)

Calling function `u()` assigns strings to string array `S[]` which is of size `s`

TIO link has some functionality in the footer to clear assigned variables.

Might be able to save a byte or two by using `FS=""`, but this is a more general solution.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, <s>105</s> 87 bytes

Changes: replaced poop emojis for tabs (Thanks @Adám !), replaced parenthesis and aposthrophes for template literals

```
a=[];f=s=>s.split``.map(x=>!a.includes(x)&&a.push(x)?'  '+x:x).join``.split`    `.slice(1);
```

Takes a string, returns an array of strings.
A big chunk is converting from String->[char]->String->[string]. whitout conversions, this becomes:

```
a=[];f=s=>s.map(x=>!a.includes(x)&&a.push(x)?'\n'+x:x).join``.slice(1);
```

takes char array, returns newline separated string (71 bytes).

Also, this is my first post on this stack exchange!

Comment: Welcome to the site and nice first post! This is actually **105** bytes in UTF-8, due to the emojis and we hope you'll continue to golf here!

Comment: Can't you use a literal tab instead of `︎` to save the extra bytes?

Comment: Ohh i thought poop emojis were 2 bytes long... Fixed

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 61 bytes

```powershell
$args|% t*y|%{if(!($r-cmatch"^[$_]")){$r+=,''};$r[-1]+=$_}
$r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZFPb4JAEMXvfIrpZHRB4dBrG5MaD169G2sQlkoEl@5ibIN8dvpWrRJ@j5k3fyBsY87aur2uqkEKmlE3SGq/3GVE7eT3MurKInwJxSZZnbbZnj/Xst1wFHVip7NYqf5d7Dp53Uxnsu0DsUMfBB9hQLjikOvSOX83Tckxcc0xI@CbicD70b1ZrWhFY1rQUqF1hSpy6NjLwsvy0cvz@dwv9I@nl6f11URrDlJQP8tMjzclVXnQlBvt6GhaOht7oJ3O0pPTZAqaqFgloAIlOAANCOTA@MT57GggrY/OPsIa6M6XM5ACrPQToPC1iYqCiC40ou76MeJiEv3T6KzVOf6@bG@21e5UtTDGOBRxV5Ml5HuBE/3NjzmO3v4nOOiHPw)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, <s>111</s> 96 bytes

```
#(reverse(reduce(fn[[f & r :as R]i](if((set(apply str R))i)(cons(str f i)r)(cons(str i)R)))[]%))
```

As Jim Carrey would say: Beautiful! :D

Answer (score 0):

## Gema, 20 characters

```
?=${$1;\n}@set{$1;}?
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ gema '?=${$1;\n}@set{$1;}?' <<< 'mississippi'

m
i
ssissi
ppi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/395WpVrF0Domr9ahOLUExKy1//8/N7O4GIQKCjIB)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 159 bytes

134 bytes of lambda + 25 bytes for HashSet import. Rip all linters and IDEs.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
...
s->{HashSet h=new HashSet();return s.chars().mapToObj(c->(char)c+"").reduce("",(x,y)->x+(!h.isEmpty()&h.add(y)?","+y:y)).split(",");};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY/BasMwDIbveQrNhyKTxg@w0I4w1u0yVuhuYwfXcRpncWIsp2sIffYsJWWXXVYQSL/0f/CrkkeZVPnXaKxrfYBq0qILphYvksqdDmn055J5L3tKI1VLIniVphki0wTtC6k0bIZd8KY5fHxCgfMIxNNz5Lp9bRRQkGFqx9bkYCcWf@3SH4jDEG2ggNVIyXq4ZoBy1ehvuCrkqdeh8w2QUKX0hFxY6d7bt32FKlnjZclVzBgXXued0sjYEk/LnifrU4x3pTD0ZF3okS9KIfMce/7Alizu73vOBbnaBJz0FDoddz0FbUXbBeGmnKFucP5fhHZOjoUokFlDdCnnDOOcp9F/wS1sYQGP8HwblmXZjUAu7W3E7D6fxx8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 6 bytes

```
⊜□\+◰.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_9_0__ZiDihpAg4oqc4pahXCvil7AuCgpmICJtaXNzaXNzaXBwaSIKZiAiUCBQICYgQyBHIgpmICJBQUEiCmYgIkFkYW0iCmYgIiIK)

```
⊜□\+◰.
     .  # duplicate
    ◰   # mark firsts
  \+    # cumulative sum
⊜□      # split
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 5 bytes

```
ÞUÞṗḢ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCLDnlXDnuG5l+G4oiIsIiIsIkhlbGxvIl0=)

```
  Þṗ  # Partition before
ÞU    # Uniquity mask
    Ḣ # Remove leading empty list
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 109 bytes

```scala
_.foldLeft(Seq.empty)((l,c)=>if(l.exists(_.contains(c)))l.dropRight(1):+l.last.appended(c)else l:+c.toString)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZY_BasMwDIbvewqRQ7FpZxi7jEBKQw-97BBWdhqjmNhuDXLsxR5sjD7JLrls79QX2HNMaQYLDViSJX2_JX9-x1qivO1Oq5WTtgGlDRw0omc8h8fGJijg4wrOdeN9DtvU2mYPxRK2-uVpyJ576Os1meu7k9sJ41Hda5MYEUK7kN45Y7ioebG0hqHQbzamyHai9k2ioZHVnHMUqvXhwe4Pid3wfI4CZUxChqAbpRUxGqMGzOe1SH4YzP-G_hxpRRmjbhOjLVnmbIz9CcFmHIqiX5aq2SKzZEOPLuc2v9BWUMEM1rAZKSuCqUx-1rt17zZTaVmWI9E5myBKujFDDykySeam9D9JrePw264b4i8)